# How to automatically add a scrollbar to a tkinter window when it gets to big for the screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display a list of files being processed from a directory. If the directory has a lot of files the window gets bigger than the screen and cuts off without adding a scroll bar.
I've seen some solutions to add scrollbars to widgets but I didn't seeanything to manage the entire window or how to have it appear just when the content doesn't fit like most other app windows. Is there a command to let the operating system manage when the scrollbar appears?
Here's the code I have so far, at the moment it just displays file names but I want to add what's done to them later.

```
import tkinter
from pathlib import Path

def start():
    progressWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(mainWindow)
    tkinter.Label(progressWindow,text="File name").grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="w")
    tkinter.Label(progressWindow,text="Analysis results").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
    tkinter.Label(progressWindow, text="File moved and renamed").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="w")
    gridRow = 1
    sourcePath = Path(r"C:\Users\Sulley\Downloads")
    for file in sourcePath.iterdir():
        if not file.is_file():
            continue
        if not file.suffix == ".pdf":
            continue
        tkinter.Label(progressWindow,text=file.name).grid(row=gridRow,column=0, sticky="w")
        gridRow += 1
    tkinter.Button(progressWindow,text="Done", command=progressWindow.destroy).grid(row=gridRow, column=1)

mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
mainWindow.title("Sort Bill PDFs")
# Go/cancel
tkinter.Button(mainWindow,text="Cancel", command=quit).pack()
tkinter.Button(mainWindow,text="Go!", command=start).pack()
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Choose on solution from [tkinter - scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpython%5d%5btkinter%5d%20scrollbar%20is%3aquestion)